# Script to check data from Excel file to web page

Tags: php, javascript, forms, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with about 300 names which includes ID, first name and second name (different column each).

I have a website (not in English) that has forms to fill with people ID, first name, last name and a search button.

There's 2 outcomes that the search can provide:

- either there will be one line massage under the form which indicate me NO result
- or a new window will open to fill some details which means to me YES result (I don't need to fill those details, the new window display is the final result) and a new search will begin.

I need a script to auto insert the details from the Excel spreadsheet and return me yes or no results (or whatever 2 options result).

If the results can be inported from the Excel file that will be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ummm. what? This site is not a "write code for me" type of place. Your question is vague, far too broad, and will be closed. oh, and does that "one line massage" include a happy ending?

Comment: gimme $100, I'll do it for you! *Seriously, why is more and more people think stackoverflow is the place to get free script???

Comment: i'm not looking for free script to be made for me by someone.
im looking to know if there's one available over the net and if not to know if it can be done and for how much,if there's one here interested

Comment: do some codes. when you stuck on particular line, error, or feature, ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking at libraries like [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net), then you can ask any specific questions over code that you're having problems with, but don't expect people to write your application for you